# Windows Phone 8 with Sharepoint 2010 Connectivity

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, rest

How we connect Windows Phone 8 to Sharepoint 2010 and get list data using web services

I found connectivity for Windows phone 7 with Sharepoint 2010 but not found with windows phone 8.Is it same for both?

Noting Found on net also.

Any idea Help me a lot.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's the same webservices; there is no difference between the two. You should be able to use the same webservices in the same way on both WP7 and WP8.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I will test when Windows Phone 8 SDK launch.